# AngularTS, subscription testing

Tags: angular, typescript

I am wondering how to change and test the value returned from a subscription, within an if statement.

Using a method that subscribes to a data service set out like so:

```
    this.service.returnResponse().subscribe((value) => {
        if (value !== null) {
            ....test in here
        }
    });
```

The data within the test will be returned as null, I want to change the value returned to a parameter I have set, such as:

```
   it('should query data service and subscribe to response TRUE ()', () => {
      const response: string[] = ['NOT-NULL'];

      service.returnEndResponseMS().subscribe(value => {
         value ==..andReturn(response)

      });

      component.subscribeToConnection();
      fixture.detectChanges();
   });
```

How do we change the returned value of a subscription in order to test an inner conditional block?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
  it('should query data service and subscribe to response TRUE ()', () => {

    const response: string[] = ['NOT-NULL'];
    spyOn(service, 'returnResponse').and.returnValue(of(response));

    service.returnResponse).subscribe(value => {
      expect(something to be equal to something);
      expect(something to be called);

    });

    component.subscribeToConnection();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```